# add/remove data from table from previous page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an HTML table being displayed from php data and I'm trying to move data from one table to another based on what is clicked. I cannot get it to move from table to another but I"m not getting any code error.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>View Requests</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<center>
<a href="../index.php">Home</a> &middot; <a href="../controlpanel/requests">Requests</a>
</center>
</div>

<?php
require_once '../../scripts/app_config.php';
require_once '../../scripts/database_connection.php';

// get results from database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp")
or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th>Username</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['User_id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['First_name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Last_name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Username'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="submit.php?id=' . $row['User_id'] . '">Approve</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
// close table>
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

### PHP EDIT SCRIPT:

```
  <html>
<head>
<title>View Requests</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<center>
<a href="../index.php">Home</a> &middot; <a href="../controlpanel/requests">Requests</a> &middot; <a href="../allusers">All Users</a>
</center>

<?php
require_once '../../scripts/app_config.php';
require_once '../../scripts/database_connection.php';


$id = $_GET['id'];


    $sql = ("INSERT INTO users
    SELECT * FROM temp WHERE User_id = $id ");
    mysql_query($sql)
        or die(mysql_error());


?>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which of the two phps are you showing? I assume submit.php. Is the `AND` operator case insensitive in PHP? I only ever use &&

Comment: index.php  and submit.php

Comment: Any PHP errors? Add error handling, why is the sql string in brackets? I would expect `$sql="INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES ('".$id."')"` or similar

Comment: I added error handling. Am I just not pulling the data correctly? I am utterly lost

Comment: No I did not get any error messages but the database is still empty

Comment: side note, get rid of all the `PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"` crap, we're not in 2005. Use HTML 5.

Comment: Thanks, that was left over from a previous project I was using a template from

Comment: Turns out I was calling to the ID incorrectly. I will put the resolved code above

Comment: Then close it instead of answering it.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use

```
$id = $_get['id];
```

and in the insert statement i had to replace id with User_id

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>View Requests</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
    <center>
    <a href="../index.php">Home</a> &middot; <a href="../controlpanel/requests">Requests</a> &middot; <a href="../allusers">All Users</a>
    </center>

    <?php
    require_once '../../scripts/app_config.php';
    require_once '../../scripts/database_connection.php';


    $id = $_GET['id'];


        $sql = ("INSERT INTO users
        SELECT * FROM temp WHERE User_id = $id ");
        mysql_query($sql)
            or die(mysql_error());


    ?>




    </body>
    </html>
```